# Git - Using system proxy

Tags: git, github, proxy

I have some problems and ant to use a proxy for my gift connection. I know two ways to do that

1. Define proxy in `.gitconfig`

   ```
   [http]
       proxy = http://username:password@proxydomain:port
       sslverify = false
   [https]
       proxy = http://username:password@proxydomain:port
       sslverify = false
   ```
2. Use environment variable

   ```
   set http_proxy=http://username:password@proxydomain:port
   set https_proxy=http://username:password@proxydomain:port
   ```

Is it possible that Git use **system settings** for proxy? like browsers or other software without set it manually?

Comment: now there is only one answer to all Github related question... **Consider using Gitlab**

Comment: @DudeCoder not until they've sorted their 500 errors.